# Mute AVPlayer when other audio starts playing in the same app

Tags: ios, avplayer

I use `AVPlayer` to play a M3U playlist from Internet in my app. The same app shows news articles and those articles can contain different embedded videos (Youtube, Vimeo, Twitter, etc.) The app uses `UIWebBrowser` to display articles.

Now I want to mute the `AVPlayer` when any of the videos starts playing (when `UIWebBrowser` starts playing a video). And I want to unmute the `AVPlayer` when user done watching videos. Setting video to pause can be counted as done too.

Is there a way to detect when audio starts playing in the same app? And when it stops?

Comment: you should use comman `avplayer` to play all media, so at a time only one media can be played!

Comment: @Lion this could help but most media are played by web browser control.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
```

To allow sounds to be played, mixes.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for audio played by other apps. I need a solution for two audio sources within the same app. And I can't use ambient category for a number of reasons anyway. One of the reasons: I need the AVPlayer to continue playing even when app is suspended.

Comment: @Bobrovsky have you found any solution for this?